# How to display List of XML in Listview

Tags: android, list, listview, xml-parsing

I want to display the attributes of this XML file

```
<carparkData>
    <carpark name="PARNELL" spaces="105"> </carpark>
    <carpark name="ILAC" spaces="519"> </carpark>
    <carpark name="JERVIS" spaces="627"> </carpark>
    <carpark name="ARNOTTS" spaces="162"> </carpark>
</carparkData>
```

so far I have the attributes adding to the list (I think)

```
public class HandelingXML extends DefaultHandler {


ArrayList<CarparkNode> carparks = new ArrayList<CarparkNode>();
CarparkNode carparkNode = null;

public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if(localName.equals("carpark")) {
        CarparkNode pageNode = new CarparkNode();
        CarparkNode.carPark = atts.getValue("name");
        CarparkNode.spaces = atts.getValue("spaces");
        carparkNode.carparks.add(pageNode);
    }
```

adding to a sentence

```
public static class CarparkNode {
    public static String carPark;
    public static String spaces;

    public void setCarPark(String c)
    {
        carPark = c;        
    }
    public void setSpace (String s)
    {
        spaces = s;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return carPark + "   " + spaces + " spaces";
    }
    public ArrayList<CarparkNode> carparks = new ArrayList<CarparkNode>();      
}
```

I want to call the list and display it in a list view but can't it to work

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        tvcp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcp);

        StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
        String fullURL = URL.toString();
        try{
            URL website = new URL(fullURL);
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            HandelingXML gettingData = new HandelingXML();
            xr.setContentHandler(gettingData);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
            //String information = gettingData.getInformation();
            //tvcp.setText(information);
            //int position;
            CarparkNode carparkNode = carparkNode.carparks.get(position);
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, carparkNode.carparks));

            }catch(Exception e){
            tvcp.setText("error");
        }

    }
```

if I could get help with this it would be appreciated

Comment: what issues are you experiencing? does it throw any kind of exception? does the document get parsed? put some effort into formulating what exactly do is the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom listview adapter to acheive this . [See this](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/) for further details

Comment: no, it's not necessary. it's probable that OP will end up doing that but that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: but how do I get the problem I'm having fixed I'm new to this could I get a code example of a solution cause i've been trying to get it working for over a week looking at various different examples

Comment: All you need is to create a custom layout of list view item then parse the data and add listviews accordingly. Since you are using a single string so embedding four values in an arraylist will not be an ideal situation